# How to use std::transform with templates

Tags: c++, templates, stl, stl-algorithm

I am struggling to find out why I can't get transform to work with a template class.

Here's a simplified version of the template class :

```
template<typename T>
class base
{
public :
  base() : all_() {}
  ~base() {}
public:
  bool add(T t)
  {
    typename vector<T>::iterator itr 
      = lower_bound(all_.begin(), all_.end(), t);
    if ( itr == all_.end() || *itr != t )
      {
        all_.push_back(t);
        cout << "ok" << endl;
        return true;
      }
    cout << "failed" << endl;
    return false;
  }
  static bool addTo(base<T> *c, T t)
  {
    return c->add(t);
  }
private :
  vector<T> all_;
};
```

And this is where I am trying to use transform to capture all the bool output from the add member function :

```
main()
{
  base<int> test;
  vector<bool> results;
  vector<int> toAdd;
  toAdd.push_back(10);
  toAdd.push_back(11);
  toAdd.push_back(10);
  transform( toAdd.begin(), toAdd.end(),
             back_inserter(results),
             bind1st( (bool(*)(base<int>*,int))base<int>::addTo, &test ) );
}
```

The aim is to insert each member of the toAdd container using either  base::add or base::addTo, and capture the bool results in the vector results

Comment: What's the question? If it's "why doesn't this code compile", then among other things function definitions in C++ must have a return type, and `main` has return type `int` ;-)

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve in transform?

Comment: Correct - can't get it to compile.  Giving main the full type is not a prerequisite of any compiler I've every used.

Comment: The aim is to insert each member of the toAdd container suing the either base<int>::add or base<int>::addTo, and capture the bool results in the vector<bool> results.

Comment: @youngthing: I'm just kidding, I was stalling while I worked out an actual answer. If you want your compiler to catch that particular error, try g++ with -pedantic.

Comment: @youngthing: Then you just haven’t used a lot of compilers. g++ requires return type `int` on `main` (with the `-pedantic` flag set, which should always be the case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
  transform( toAdd.begin(), toAdd.end(),
         back_inserter(results),
         bind1st( mem_fun(&base<int>::add), &test ) );
```

The problem isn't the template, it's that bind1st relies on extra support to work (see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/AdaptableBinaryFunction.html). AFAIK it can't ever operate on plain old function pointers.

`boost::bind` can do more things, if you want to bring that in. For this situation you don't need it, though: `mem_fun` turns a non-static member function into an adaptable binary function. `addTo` therefore isn't needed either, but if you did need to use a static member function in a similar situation then there's `ptr_fun`.

Comment: That works.  
Thanks for the tips, especially the pedantic one.

Comment: And the *reason* it works is that `bind1st` doesn't accept ordinary function pointers. It requires functor objects. The `mem_fun` and `ptr_fun` functions turn function pointers into functors suitable for use with the binders.

Comment: @RobKennedy: thanks, that makes a lot of sense, and something I haven't picked up from the Josutis STL book yet.  
I would give you and onebyone a rec if a could!

Comment: @Rob: thanks, you beat me to it while I was looking up the SGI docs to remember what the darn thing's called. Adaptable.

Comment: And good point about ptr_fun being relevant too, I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your base class:

```
typedef base<T>* first_argument_type;
typedef T second_argument_type;
typedef bool result_type;

bool operator () (base<T> *c, T t) const {
    return c->add(t);
}
```

and change transform to:

```
transform(toAdd.begin(), toAdd.end(),
          back_inserter(results), bind1st(base<int>(), &test ));
```

Comment: That would be okay if my class (base) was only going to be storing a container - I would not mind committing operator() to just adding an item.  My proper code though has base responsible for a lot more.

Comment: You wouldn't have to place add in the 'base' class you could create a small struct, say 'Adder' which contains the code I supplied. Then replace base<int> with 'Adder'. But the mem_fun adapter works as well ;)